# How to convert two strings into single dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to convert two string values into single dict like this

```
string1='red blue white'
string2= 'first second third'
dict={'red':first,'blue':second.'white':third}
```

But here i can't use loops!! Is there any other way without loop?.
Help me!! 
Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use loops?  Is this homework?

Comment: I actually I'm trying to use this with large amount of data due to python slowness I'm avoiding loops

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> string1 = 'red blue white'
>>> string2 = 'first second third'
>>> dict(zip(string1.split(), string2.split()))
{'blue': 'second', 'red': 'first', 'white': 'third'}
```